# How to access a abstract undefined function from abstract class in c#?

Tags: c#

How can I do this?

```
public abstract class A {

    protected abstract async Task foo(int a);

    protected async Task bar(int a) {
        await foo(a);
    }
}

public class B : A {
    public async Task foo(int a) {
        return a + 1;
    }
}
```

basically I want to declare a async function without a body in in the abstract class, also have another function in the abstract class use the function like it existed. But have that function defined with a body in the class that implements the abstract class.

Note: the `foo` in my code has something in it that uses await, so it has to be async.

Is this possible?

Comment: I dont see how that question answers my question?

Comment: @servy as much as both this and the question you linked to are in the same domain, they are not duplicates of each other.  The question you linked was primarily about the compiler warning you get when you don't use await in an async function.  This one is more about defining that in the first place.   The accepted answer to that question won't help this user.

Comment: Async is not like every other part of method declaration. You cannot force something to be async. All you can do is specify return type as `Task`

Comment: Sam I am's answer below is correct. Just get rid of the async in the abstract declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make `foo` `async` in your abstract class.  As long as it returns a `Task` you can still override it with an `async` implementation.

Other things you need to account for:

- you need the `override` keyword on the `foo` function in `B`
- If you want to return an int, it needs to be `Task<int>`
- they either both have to be protected or both public.  You can't have one protected and the other public.

Comment: Sorry - you are right - I was getting confused with public vs internal class declarations

Answer (score -2):

You are missing the override keyword:

```
public abstract class A {

    public abstract Task<int> foo(int a);

    protected async Task bar(int a) {
        await foo(a);
    }
}

public class B : A {
    public override async Task<int> foo(int a) {
        return a + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: that doesn't compile

Comment: Change the method from protected to public.

Comment: still doesn't compile

Comment: still doesn't compile

Comment: remove async from method

Comment: Changing it to from protected to public wouldn't fix it. Also, I'm not sure this answers, exactly the question